# publishing multiple database projects from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

We have a VS solution that has around 11 database projects, when pulling updated from our solution control I want to publish the databases to my local sql server, so that it reflects any changes since the last pull.
It is very manual to open each project, go to the publish profiles, select the publish.xml and then confirm the deployment.
Is there a way of either with script, PS, or a c# app; to go through each of the database projects and publish them?